# How to increment data and time in a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a game time that would keep counting on even if you werent activly in-game, this game world also runs faster and a bit differently.

so i'm setting up an epoch as the refernce to do all the calculations.

I will have to, say increment game minutes for every 60 game seconds, and game hours for every 60 game mins and so on, I'm just a lil stuck on the increment part, can any one help?

```
import time

#Earth Time
seconds = int(time.time())
mins = seconds / 60
hours = mins/ 60
days = hours / 24
years = days / 365

print("Seconds:",seconds)
print("Mins:",mins)
print("Hours:",hours)
print("Days:",days)
print("Years:",years)

#Game Time
gseconds = seconds * 25
gmins = 0
ghours = 0
gdays = 0
gyears = 0

print("GSeconds:",gseconds)
print("GMins:",gmins)
print("GHours:",ghours)
print("GDays:",gdays)
print("GYears:",gyears)

count = 0

for var in gseconds: #stuck here
        count = count +1

print(count)
```

something like:

```
for var in range (gseconds): #stuck here
        count = count +1
        if count >=60:
                gmins= gmins +1
                count = 0
        if gmins >= 60:
                ghours = ghours +1
                gmins = 0
        if ghours >= 24:
                gdays = gdays +1
```

Comment: Why store minutes, hours, etc. at all? Just store the seconds, and calculate minutes, hours etc. when needed, using simple division by 60, 3600, etc.

Comment: so that i can later add days, months and years, even moon phases. I am in essence creating a calendar initiated from epoch but running about 25x faster, and would need to do check on the current time, day, month etc.

Comment: Sorry, I never done anything like this but is there a reason you aren't using datetime? For instance, current_time = (datetime.datetime.now() - start_time)?

Comment: I used seconds = int(time.time()) as its the amount of seconds that passed since 1st jan 1970 (i think) and gives a reference point for the other calculations

Comment: But even then you can calculate those when needed. Just have some methods `get_day` that calculates the current day from the elapsed seconds, etc. Much simpler this way.

Answer (score 1):

Just use every second to increment the proper time value:

```
for var in range (gseconds):
    count += 1
    if count >= 60:
            gmins += 1
    if gmins >= 3600:
            ghours += 1
    if ghours >= (24 * 3600):
            gdays += 1
```